# Cannot rejoin AD domain

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have two Virtualbox VMs both of which attached the internal network. They are

- Windows Server 2019 as the Active Directory domain controller and DNS.
- Windows 10, named ADM1 and joined the domain

Yesterdays I created some new users on AD, and I had issues to log those new users onto ADM1. The error message was: (all the following error messages are translated, not sure if they are accurate)

> The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

I was sure that it was not about DNS, because I pinged from ADM1 to server and from server to ADM1, and the domain names were correctly resolved (although ADM1 did not respond to ping). And the NETLOGON service was running and set to start automatically on ADM1.

So the next I did was that I removed ADM1 from Active Directory and tried to rejoin the Win10 machine to the domain, using a local admin account.

Before rejoining the domain, I removed the antivirus on ADM1. When rejoining the domain, I renamed the machine to ADM2, and used the administrator account of Active Directory. But the error message showed up:

> The specified computer account could not be found. Contact an administrator to verify the account is in the domain. If the account has been deleted unjoin, reboot, and rejoin the domain.

I wonder what else I can do.

Comment: Is ADM1 the server or the Windows 10 computer?

Comment: Sorry, it's the Win10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem through, on Win10 machine, Start -> Settings -> Accounts -> Access company or school resources -> click on my domain and disconnect from the domain. This will move the Win10 machine from the domain to a workgroup, and then I can rejoin the domain without problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).